# How to handle dependent behavior in a domain class?

Tags: algorithm, oop, design-patterns, domain-driven-design

Let's say I've got a domain class, which has functions, that are to be called in a sequence. Each function does its job but if the previous step in the sequence is not done yet, it throws an error. The other way is that each function completes the step required for it to run, and then executes its own logic. I feel that this way is not a good practice, since I am adding multiple responsibilities, and the caller wont know what all operations can happen when he invokes a method.

My question is, how to handle dependent scenarios in DDD. Is it the responsibility of the caller to invoke the methods in the right sequence? Or do we make the methods handle the dependent operations before it's own logic?

Comment: Perhaps you could provide more specific scenarios to help us dive deeper into your problem.

Comment: Hey, my use case is regarding file operations. My domain would be File class, and the methods would be upload, convert, download. Now convert can't happen without upload, and imo, calling upload inside convert wouldn't be the best practice. That's what I need suggestions on. I think this isn't specific to my use case though :)

Answer (score 0):

> Is it the responsibility of the caller to invoke the methods in the right sequence?

It's ok if those methods have a business meaning. For example the client may book a flight, and then book a hotel room. Both of those is something the client understands, and it is the client's logic to call them in this sequence. On the other hand, inserting the reservation into the database, then committing (or whatever) is technical. The client should not have to deal with that at all. Or "initializing" an object, then calling other methods, then calling "close".

Requiring a sequence of technical calls is a form of *temporal coupling*, it is considered a bad practice, and is not directly related to DDD.

The solution is to model the problem better. There is probably a higher level use-case the caller wants achieved with this call sequence. So instead of publishing the individual "steps" required, just support the higher use-case as a whole.

In general you should always design with the goal to get any sequence of valid calls to actually *mean* something (as far as the language allows).

**Update**: A possible model for the mentioned "File" domain:

```java
public interface LocalFile {
    RemoteFile upload();
}

public interface RemoteFile {
    RemoteFile convert(...);

    LocalFile download();
}
```

Comment: Hey Robert thanks for the reply. I get what you're saying. I am not sure if this can be modeled better. My use case is around file operations. My domain would be File class, and the methods would be upload, convert, download. Now convert can't happen without upload, and imo, calling upload inside convert wouldn't be the best practice. How do you suggest to model it better? Moreover, the client in this case would be me only. This is not something that's getting exposed, all the callers of this layer would be aware of the sequence.

Comment: @lazyloader See update above. As you see, any combination of calls in this domain results in some meaningful, albeit maybe only theoretical, result.

Answer (score 0):

From my point of view, what you are describing is the orchestration of domain model operations. That's the job of the application layer, the layer upon domain model. You should have an application service that would call the domain model methods in the right sequence, and it also should take into account whether some step has left any task undone, and in such case, tell the next step to perform it.

Answer (score 0):

TLDR; Scroll to the bottom for the answer, but the backstory will give some good context.

If the caller into your domain must know the order in which to call things, then you have missed an opportunity to encapsulate business logic in your domain, which is a symptom of an [anemic domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anemic_domain_model).

@RobertBräutigam made a very good point:

> Requiring a sequence of technical calls is a form of temporal coupling, it is considered a bad practice, and is not directly related to DDD.

This is true, but it is *worse* when you do it with your domain model because non-domain concerns get intermixed with domain concerns. Intent becomes lost in a sea of non business logic. If you can, you look for a higher-order [aggregate](https://www.martinfowler.com/bliki/DDD_Aggregate.html) that encapsulates the ordering. To borrow Robert's example, rather than booking a flight then a hotel room, and forcing that on the client, you could have a **Vacation** aggregate take both and validate it.

I know that sounds *wrong* in your case, and I suspect you're right. There's a clear dependency that *can't* happen all at once, so we can't be the end of the story. When you have a clear dependency with intermediate transactions that must occur before the "final" state, we have... orchestration (think sagas, distributed transactions, domain events and all that goodness).

What you describe with file operations spans across transactions. The manipulation (state change) of a domain is transactional at each point in a distributed transaction, but is not transactional overall. So when @choquero70 says

> you are describing is the orchestration of domain model operations. That's the job of the application layer, the layer upon domain model.

that's also correct. Orchestration is key. Each step must manipulate the state of the domain once, and once only, and leave it in a valid state, but it OK for there to be multiple steps.

*Each of those individual points along the timeline are valid moments in the state of your domain*.

So, back to your model. If you expose a single interface with multiple possible calls to *all* steps, then you leave yourself open to things being called out of order. Make this **impossible** or at least improbable. Orchestration is not just about what to do, but what to prevent from happening. Create smaller interfaces/classes to avoid accidentally increasing the "surface area" of what could be misused accidentally.

In this way, you are guiding the caller on what to do next by feeding them valid intermediate states. But, **and this is the important part**, the burden on what to call in what order is *not* on the caller. Sure, the caller could know what to do, but why force it.

Your basic algorithm is the same: upload, transform, download.

> Is it the responsibility of the caller to invoke the methods in the right sequence?

Not exactly. Is the responsibility of the caller to choose from legitimate choices given the state of your domain. It's "your" responsibility to present these choices via business methods on your correctly modeled [moment/interval](http://curtis.schlak.com/2013/05/09/modeling-in-color-part-iii.html) aggregate suitable for the caller to use.

> Or do we make the methods handle the dependent operations before it's own logic?

If you've setup orchestration correctly, this won't be necessary. But it does make sense to validate anyway.

On a side note, each step of the orchestration you do should be very linear in nature. I tell my developers to be suspicious of an orchestration step that has an **if** statement in it. If there's an **if** it's likely better to be part of another orchestration step or encapsulated in business logic.