# DDD: Why separate repository methods to different interfaces?

Tags: oop, domain-driven-design

According to Vaughn Vernon's [IDDD_Samples](https://github.com/VaughnVernon/IDDD_Samples/blob/master/iddd_agilepm/src/main/java/com/saasovation/agilepm/domain/model/product/ProductRepository.java), a repository interface has some methods: issuing an identity(`nextIdentity`), saving an entity(`save`), getting an entity(`productOfId`), removing an entity(`remove`) and so on.

However, it is rare to use all the methods in a single use-case. For example, in the case of creating a new entity, two methods `nextIdentity` and `save` is used, but the others are not used.

From the point of view of I[nterface Segregation Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle), I thought that the methods of the repository should be separated into some interfaces. How does this help?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

My [long-winded answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55096822/how-to-handle-dependent-behavior-in-a-domain-class/55133001#55133001) to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55096822/64348) boiled down to minimizing the ability of a client from doing the "wrong" thing.

Smaller interfaces introduced and used at the "right" times can prevent a number of bugs and accidental issues developers may incur.

This means your instincts are leading you to the right direction. You can pass these "smaller" interfaces via [dependency injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) or other means to components that have a more narrow scheme of what they need to do (i.e. components designed for each use case). This prevents you or others from doing something you "shouldn't" automatically.

Answer (score 0):

> From the point of view of Interface Segregation Principle, I thought that the methods of the repository should be separated into some interfaces. How does this help?

I would describe it this way: Interface Segregation comes at a *cost*.

In this case, segregating this interface introduces eight? new role interfaces that each need to be managed.  Possibly more, possibly fewer, depending on how many distinct use cases we are trying to manage, and how much fine grained control we want to support.

My suspicion is that, for Vernon's purposes, what he wants is the [banana](https://www.johndcook.com/blog/2011/07/19/you-wanted-banana/) -- a clear demonstration of the responsibilities of repositories without dragging in the gorilla and the rest of the jungle.

Another way of expressing the same idea: the responsibilities here have a lot of [cohesion](https://www.theregister.co.uk/2006/06/27/getting_together_time/) -- when you replace your persistence solution, it is likely that the implementation of all of these responsibilities will need to change, and it is natural that they change together.

The best fit solution for a tutorial, where you are trying to present to a student a single idea, and the best fit solution for a living system, where you frequently need to make fine grained changes to the implementation of responsibilities, are not necessarily the same.

Horses for courses.